# Is Earning From YouTube Halal?

Tags: halal-haram

Is Earning From YouTube Halal? If I block abusive and sensitive Advertisement?

Some people say it's haram and some people say it's halal.

Can you explain it?

Comment: You're getting money from youtube directly and they're the ones that get money from advertising.  Either way there's no haraam in it.

Comment: But some people say it's haram. But i don't understand from which perspective it's Haram?

Comment: Perhaps you should've asked them why they think it's Haram. Could it be because of the *type of content* you display?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my content.All contents are Islamic.